# Split jQuery collection into an array of individual jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there is a way to split a jQuery selector which contains a collection of elements into an array of selectors, one for each element. For example, I have:

```
fields = row.find('input');
```

which returns a selector containing multiple input elements. I know I can use

```
fields.eq(index).val()
```

to access individual values, but is there an easy way to construct or convert fields to an array of selectors so I can just use

```
fields[index].val()
```

#### Edit:

Yes I realize you can use .toArray(), but as has been pointed out below, that returns an array of DOM elements. Then you'd have to loop through to convert these to selectors - too much extra work.

Comment: Why does `fields.eq(index).val()` not meet your needs? It seems odd to do extra work to achieve something thats already possible.

Comment: `$(fields[index]).val()` will also do

Comment: @RoyiNamir true, but that's using a jQuery object to get a DOMElement to turn it back in to a jQuery object, which is completely redundant.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think he wants the `[]` access . it's possible. but it has a cost. As in general - I think your comment is right. no need to add extra features.

Comment: I guess either .eq or re-selecting are the simplest syntaxes possible. Was just wondering if jQuery had anything built in like a split command, but for selector collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var $input = $("input");
var $$input = $input.map(function() {
    return $(this);
}).get();

console.log($input instanceof Object); // true
console.log($input instanceof jQuery); // true
console.log($$input instanceof Array); // true

$input.eq(3).val("test");
$$input[3].val("test");
```

But this is absurd.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't quite work. The data types appear to be correct but then `fields[0].val()` doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm that does seem to work, I must have had something else wrong in my code. But isn't .get() supposed to return DOM objects?

Comment: [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) simply returns a JavaScript array of all _elements_. In the above example, each _element_ is a jQuery object which contains a single DOM element.

Answer (score 3):

How about a small plugin to do this for you?

```
$.fn.toJqArray = function(){
   var arr = [];
    $(this).each(function(){
       arr.push($(this)); 
    });
    return arr;
};

var inputs = $('input').toJqArray();
var value = inputs[0].val();
```

[Here's a fiddle with usage.](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/svdsvy70/)

Comment: Perfect! But unfortunately not standard in jQuery. They should add it.

Answer (score 2):

IF you use pure javascript, you access to inputs by an array, but if you need with jQuery you can make a loop:

```
var arrFields = [];
fields.each(function() {
     arrFields.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(arrFields);
```

good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can use both jQuery [**`toArray() function`**](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) or [**`jQuery.makeArray() function`**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/).
Both of them will return an array of DOM elements.

The difference is that **`toArray`** function converts only jQuery result object to an array:

```
$("p").toArray(); // correct
```

**`$.makeArray`** is more multipurpose and complicated. It converts **any array-like objects** to a proper **JS array**.

For example,

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

actually returns array-like `nodeList`, but not an array.

You cannot do:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); 
elems.reverse(); // error. reverse() is not part of nodeList
```

However, you can do

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); 
var arr = $.makeArray(elems);
arr.reverse(); // ok. arr is a JS array which has reverse() function
```

However, in case of converting jQuery selection result - there is no difference between them.
Take a look at the following code snippet which makes a jQuery selection, converts this jQuery object to two JS arrays in two different ways and works with non-jQuery DOM `innerHTML` property.

```js
var pJquery = $("p");

var pArray1 = pJquery.toArray();
var pArray2 = $.makeArray(pJquery);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = pArray1[1].innerHTML;
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += pArray2[2].innerHTML;
```

```css
p
{
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery `.toArray()`:

```
var arr = fields.toArray();
console.log(arr[0].value)
```

You can't use `.val()` here, but `.value` will work fine.

A small example/proof of concept:

```js
var fields = $('input').toArray();
$.each(fields, function(i, o) {
  console.log(o.value + ' == ' + fields[i].value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="a" value="a" />
<input name="b" value="b" />
<input name="c" value="c" />
<input name="d" value="d" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use [.toArray()](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/)

```
var fieldsArray = [];
fieldsArray = fields.toArray();
```

Answer (score -2):

Each html element, if it don't posess an id, isn't guarentee to have a unique selector.